# removing first character from jquery selector with javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I tried the following:

```
var s = $('body span:contains("product_id")').next().text();
s.substring(1);
```

It gets the desired text, but after page refresh the string is the same. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: remove first character from the text located in the selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two points :

-If you refresh the page what you did with javascript will be reset.

-You do nothing with `s.substring(1);` so what could happen ?

You have a bad understunding of javascript. Read some documentation/tutorials before going further.